# iisnode db connection pooling

Tags: node.js, postgresql, iis, iisnode

I'm running a *Node.js* webapp via *iisnode* hosted on *Windows Server 2012 R2 - IIS 8.5*. On client request the app needs to query data from the server DB (*PostgreSQL*).
Within standalone *Node.js* apps one usually implements DB client pooling (via *pg* module or full scale *ORM*, e.g. *Squeelize.js*). *iisnode* however fires up a *Node.js* process per client request, rendering an appwise pooling useless (as far as I understand), although it does seem to work with the *pg* modules pooling instance.
I'm fairly new to *IIS*; how would I implement an efficient DB connection pooling (or an appropriate substitute) given the setup above? E.g.:

- does *IIS / iisnode* manage db connections, perhabs via single client connection requests?
- is using appwise client pooling still the way to go?
- is using an *IIS* module preferrable?

EDIT: The [linked tutorial](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/09/creating-10-minute-todo-listing-app-on.html) for MongoDB on Tomasz Janczuks *[iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)* GitHub site uses a single client connection if I'm not mistaken, but is that fit for near production use with multiple clients and possibly complex queries?

I'd like to stick to setting up / configuring the connection inside *Node.js* if that is possible and reasonable.